# Different approaches to forcing

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, ho.history-overview, forcing

There are many different approaches to the forcing method, and I am looking for all known such approaches. So my question is:

> **Question 1.** Which different approaches to set theoretic forcing are available, and who first introduced them.

Giving (original) references for each approach is appreciated.

On the other hand it seems the approach to forcing using posets is more comfortable in forcing arguments. So my second question is:

> **Question 2.** What are the benefits of using each of these approaches with respect to other approaches?

Comment: Cohen (forcing); Vopenka (with topological spaces); Scott-Solovay (Boolean algebras); Shoenfield (unramified forcing); Kiesler (model theoretic approach); there are all those topos-theoretic approaches that I am unfamiliar with their history. And that's all that I can remember (and I may have made a few mistakes too).

Comment: Thanks, I hope hear much more about all of these approaches.

Comment: [Moore, G. **The Origins of Forcing**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X09706561) probably contains much more information. Probably more accurate than my memory, too.

Comment: Could you give a reference for Vopenka's approach? I've not heard of it (and my googling is only finding things related to forcing in the context of Vopenka's principle).

Comment: @Noah: Check out Jech's Set Theory book, Chapter 14 historical notes, p.224 there are plenty of references to Vopenka's work there (not surprisingly, since Jech was his student).

Comment: I list some relevant references in my "beginner's guide to forcing," http://alum.mit.edu/www/tchow/forcing.pdf .  See the final paragraph of Section 9.  One approach not mentioned by Asaf Karaglia is via modal logic.

Comment: There is also the naturalist account of forcing, as explained in http://jdh.hamkins.org/themultiverse/.

Comment: I think "Vopenka's approach" has a few definite meanings but one source is *The Theory of Semisets* by Vopenka and Hajek. It's a tough read but it does cover forcing in a somewhat different way than others do. As far as the topological approach goes, my understanding is that it was at least foreseen when the connection between forcing and Baire category was made. (Some conversations with people who were present at the time suggest that this connection may have been made by Cohen very early on.)

Answer (score 9):

At the risk of making things worse rather than better, let me point out that what appears to be one approach, say the Scott-Solovay version using complete Boolean algebras, is really a whole family of approaches, according to what universes you extend and how you extend them. Once you've defined a particular Boolean algebra $B$, you can do (at least) any of the following: (1) Build a cumulative hierarchy of $B$-valued sets, extending the usual cumulative hierarchy of ordinary (2-valued) sets.  (2) Give a syntactic $B$-valued interpretation of ZFC in ZFC. [Intuitively, this is "the same" as (1), but technically it's a way of getting finitary proofs of relative consistency.]  (3) Start with a countable transitive model $M$ of ZFC, interpret the definition of $B$ within $M$ to get an $M$-complete Boolean algebra $B^M\in M$, choose an $M$-generic ultrafilter $G$ in $B^M$, and form the countable transitive model $M[G]$, the smallest transitive model that includes $M$ and contains $G$. (4) Start with any model $M$ of ZFC (not necessarily well-founded), interpret the definition of $B$ in $M$ to get $B^M$, choose any ultrafilter $G$ in $B^M$ (not necessarily generic), and use it to form a 2-valued quotient $M^{(B^M)}/G$ of the Boolean-valued model $M^{(B^M)}$.